# Bash call function as array element

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm in the process of designing a bash script to execute a number of functions in a sequence (installing packages, cloning repos, for instance) and after completion send a summary report to an email address to whether the installations succeeded or failed.

An idea that popped into my head was having an associative array and having the first element of a row a function call and the second any error code generated by the function. That way I can just loop through the array to call all the functions.

Something like-

```
function foo () {
    //do something
    return success
}

function bar () {
    //do something
    return success
}

declare -A arr
arr[0,0]=foo
arr[0,1]=1
arr[1,0]=bar
arr[1,1]=1

function init () {
    for i in 0 .. 1 do
        error = arr[i,0] //this im not sure about, would this execute foo()?
        arr[i,1] = error
}

init
```

Is there a better way of doing this so that the script itself is easily modified for adding or removing functions as necessary?

Comment: Without seeing an example implementation of what you're thinking, it's hard to teel if something else may or may not be better. For example, I don't see why you need an associative array here, or how you plan to have a "row" in an array with two elements in it.

Comment: Sorry, edited for an example.

Comment: I see. You can use two arrays instead of an associative array here. `functions[0]=foo; errors[0]=1; ...`. `0,1` doesn't mean anything special in associative arrays, that's just the string `0,1`. It's not like bash internally creates a row for `0` with columns labelled `1` and `0`. What specifically is your concern about the script being "easily modified" here? You just need to add two lines for each function addition, so I'd call that easily modified.